# Creating XmlHttpsRequest with custom Twilio Parameters

Tags: xmlhttprequest, twilio

We're passing data to Studio's REST Api via xmlhttprequest. It works well while I'm only passing To, From and Body. However, I want to pass custom parameters to the api like "location" & "surveyentity" and consume it within the studio as flow.data.location and flow.data.surveyentity

Our reason of using XMLHttpRequest is that, this is how our previous developers set up our app. I understand that Twilio only has server-side SDKs and they don't recommend putting it on the front like Vue, but we're unfortunate I think. We are currently using Vue with XMLHttpRequest.

```js
async sendSmsSurvey(to, location, surveyEntity, checkedID) {
            if (location == 7 && surveyEntity == 'Google'){ 
              var url = "https://studio.twilio.com/v2/Flows/xxx/Executions";
              var phone = "xxx"; 
            }
            if (location == 8 && surveyEntity == 'Google'){
              var url = "https://studio.twilio.com/v2/Flows/xxx/Executions";
              var phone = "xxx";
            }

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", url);

            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic QUxxYyYWZiZjZhZxxxx=="); 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && surveyEntity == "Google" || surveyEntity == "EmojisGoogleRedirect" || surveyEntity == "EmojisGoogleLink") { 
                  console.log(xhr.status);
                  console.log(xhr.responseText);
                  if (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 201) {
                    //
                  } else {
                    //
                  }
              } //end xhr.readyState
            }; //end xhr.onreadystatechange

            var data = "To="+to+"&From="+phone; // I wanted to add the custom parameters here like "location" and "surveyentity".
            xhr.send(data);

          },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I understand that you are unfortunate with the way your previous developers set this up, but I must recommend that you work on moving this API request from your front-end to the back-end so that you stop exposing your Account SID and Auth Token in your application. With those two details, a malicious user can take over and abuse your Twilio account.

In the meantime, I can guide you to add the custom parameters here, but I strongly recommend using the back-end.

To add custom parameters when you trigger a Studio Flow from the API, you need to pass a [`Parameters` parameter which has a JSON object of the custom parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/execution#create-an-execution-to-trigger-a-flow). The best way to do this is to [use the `URLSearchParams` object to serialize your data](https://philna.sh/blog/2021/04/11/dont-ever-write-your-own-function-to-parse-url-parameters/).

You currently have:

```js
var data = "To="+to+"&From="+phone;
```

To start with you can improve this by using `URLSearchParams` to serialize the data:

```js
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearcParams();
urlSearchParams.append("To", to);
urlSearchParams.append("From", from);
const data = urlSearchParams.toString();
```

You need to add your custom parameters to an object which you then JSON stringify and add as a [parameter called `Parameters`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/execution#create-an-execution-to-trigger-a-flow).

```js
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearcParams();
urlSearchParams.append("To", to);
urlSearchParams.append("From", from);

const parameters = {
  surveyEntity: surveyEntity,
  location: location
};
urlSearchParams.append("Parameters", JSON.stringify(parameters));

const data = urlSearchParams.toString();
```

As I close, one more appeal. Please move this from your client side to your server side and stop exposing your credentials.

Comment: Thank you @philnash I works perfectly now! And thank you for the advice. We will be working on moving this to our back as we are well aware of this matter. For now, it's ok I guess since this isn't a public app but an internal app within our org where only 2 non-tech employees handle the sms. Thanks again. But I have a followup concern after I tried this `var data = "To="+12133885xxx+"&From="+12132779xxx+"&Parameters={\"location\": \"<location variable>\", \"entity\": \"<surveyEntity variable>\"}";` how is this different from yours?

Comment: Encoding data is never as simple as it seems, so when there is an object provided by the platform I always recommend using it. In this case, using `JSON.stringify` to create the JSON portion and `URLSearchParams` to encode that data into a form encoded string means that you have less opportunity to make mistakes yourself. I can't tell from a glance what is wrong with your version, but using the built in objects will always be safer.